How to compare two likert scale surveys by independent respondents?
I need to compare the ratings of two (multi item) scales. The catch is: the two scales, though being the same scale, are two different sets of experts.
Basic idea: do they agree or do not agree on the items of the scale.
Both groups of people were presented with different text snippets and had to fill out a survey based on those texts.
The text snippets and the scale (multiple items measured on 7 point likert scale) were the same for both groups - but the groups consisted of different people as mentioned above. How can I compare those two scales now? (Beyond summary statistics with means on all items for both groups)
Simple correlation would not work, because I don‘t have a paired structure right? I cannot match e.g. Respondent 1 from Group 1 with Respondent 1 from Group 2, as those are different people?
Would ICC be the way to go?
Thanks for your help!

do you have ratings of the same items by different users?

Correct. Both groups were presented with the same text snippets and then both groups also had the same survey for each text. However, sample size is too small for t-test (or even non-parametric tests), as there are only 4 ratings on each text snippet. And the two groups are not the same —> standard correlation would not work I guess I believe (as I could not pair the two groups due to their difference)

How many experts in each group of experts? How many text snippets? And how many Likert items on the survey for each text snippet? Depending on these numbers, you may have various options (or not...)

12 experts in each group with 4 text snippets. So you have 3 votes per Texter group. So non-parametric tests (if the means differ) would not work either I guess
